# Visual Studio 2019 Keeps Directing to MetaData Files when using Go To Definition

Tags: visual-studio, metadata, visual-studio-2019

For about a week or so, I've had an issue where, when I try to use Go To Definition on a class or method, I am redirected to a class's metadata file instead of the actual class or method.

For example, say I have a class `Foo` with a method `DoSomething()` and a class `Bar`. I instantiate an instance of `Foo` inside of `Bar` and call `Foo.DoSomething()`. If I hover over `Foo.DoSomething()` and click F12 (Go To Definition), I get directed to the `DoSomething()` method in the `Foo` metadata file, not the `DoSomething` method inside of the actual Foo class.

Cleaning and rebuilding the project does not address this issue. The only way I've been able to fix it has been deleting the .suo file in the .vs directory; doing this fixes the issue for a while, but it eventually starts happening again.

I'm using C# with Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 v16.6.3.

Does anyone know what's causing this or how to fix it more permanently?

Comment: Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem

Answer (score 1):

If the class that you are seeing metadata for is targeting a different .Net Framework version this would happen.

Make sure all projects in you solution target the same .net fx, and also remove references to the projects in your main project and  then re-add them.